# Passing a promise to Lazy load Select in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I found the jsfiddle below and I want to make the options load from a promise passed into the select tag attribute that I already have in the scope... i'm a bit of a noob when it comes to passing data into directive attributes... I just want the select to show the loading and then after the promise is loaded, then the data...

Example here (Assuming myData is an array in the $scope)

```
 <select ng-model="select.value" ng-options="o.Description for o in select.options" lazy-load-options="" data-options="select.options" option-source="myData">
    <option value=""> - Select - </option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TigerC10/g862L/

```
   link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ngModel){
        // Ajax loading notification
        $scope.options = [
            {
                Description: "Loading..."
            }
        ];

        // Control var to prevent infinite loop
        $scope.loaded = false;

        $element.bind('mousedown', function() {

            // Use setTimeout to simulate web service call
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(!$scope.loaded) {
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        $scope.options = [
                            {
                                Description: "Option 1"
                            },
                            {
                                Description: "Option 2"
                            },
                            {
                                Description: "Option 3"
                            }
                        ];
                    });
```

Comment: please update if found solution

Answer (score 2):

As the original author of that fiddle, I find it interesting that I stumbled upon this question while looking for something myself.  Though, you're using the setTimeout incorrectly in your answer to your own question.  The artificial setTimeout of 2 seconds was only a simulation of a call to a server - but in the answer to your own question you've left it in the directive after swapping out a promise.  You should remove that, and set a 1 ms timeout for the simulated clicks.

Here's a sample of what you'd want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/TigerC10/xkaqm8rw/

HTML

```
    <select ng-model="select.value" ng-options="o.Description for o in select.options" lazy-load-options="" lazy-load-from="simulatePromise()" data-options="select.options">
        <option value=""> - Select - </option>
    </select>
```

JS

```
.directive('lazyLoadOptions', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            options: '=',
            lazyLoadFrom: '&'
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ngModel){
            // Ajax loading notification
            $scope.options = [
                {
                    Description: "Loading..."
                }
            ];

            // Control var to prevent infinite loop
            $scope.loaded = false;

            $element.bind('mousedown', function() {

                // Load the data from the promise if not already loaded
                if(!$scope.loaded) {
                    $scope.lazyLoadFrom().then(function(data) {
                        $scope.options = data;

                        // Prevent the load from occurring again
                        $scope.loaded = true;

                        // Blur the element to collapse it
                        $element[0].blur();

                        // Click the element to re-open it (use timeout to escape digest cycle)
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                            $element[0].dispatchEvent(e);
                        }, 1);
                    }, function(reason){
                        // Error handling here
                        console.error(reason);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Basically, you're adding another directive scope parameter that takes the promise function and then you're executing the promise function within the directive.  The only hangup is that you have to execute the simulated clicks outside the digest cycle, or else it won't pick up on the change to the select options.  So I've wrapped those simulated clicks in a 1 ms timeout.

Comment: Actually I abandoned this, as when a model is loaded and uses it, it will not display the selected option until the event fires. I needed to show the user the model option without them having to click on it.... I just commented out the bind for now and let it just load all the options all the time so the selected option would show...

Comment: That's easy enough to overcome - preloading data to the field means you must have an object with the "value" of the select box already provided to you.  That's just one half of the equation.  However you're getting that data back, it's not hard to modify it to also provide you with the description of the select option.

Setting this as your initial option would work pretty easily:   

<option value="select.value"> {{select.description}} </option>

Answer (score 0):

i did the following... it works great...

```
<select name="mounted" 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-model="currentLot.mounted" 
    ng-options="i.name for i in scope.options" 
    lazy-load-options 
    data-options="scope.options" 
    data-prom="mountedPromiseHolder" 
    ng-readonly="readonly"  
    ng-disabled="readonly" >
```

then, controller:

```
directives.directive('lazyLoadOptions', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            options: '=',
            prom: '=' 
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ngModel){
        // Ajax loading notification


        $scope.options = [
            {
                name: "Loading..."
            }
        ];

        // Control var to prevent infinite loop
        $scope.loaded = false;

        $element.bind('mousedown', function() {

            // Use setTimeout to simulate web service call
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(!$scope.loaded) {

                    console.log("Attempting apply...");
                    console.log($scope.prom);
                    $scope.$apply(function(){

                         console.log($scope)
                          if ($scope.prom) {
                                 $scope.options = $scope.prom.promise.then(function(result) {

                                   console.log("Processing Result");
                                   console.log(result);
                                   $scope.options = result.data;

                                    $scope.loaded = true;


                              });

                          }
                    }); 

                    // Prevent the load from occurring again
                    $scope.loaded = true;

                    // Blur the element to collapse it
                    $element[0].blur();

                    // Click the element to re-open it
                    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    $element[0].dispatchEvent(e);
                }
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
    }
}]);
```